# Ruby Regular expression too big / Multiple string match

Tags: ruby, regex

I have 1,000,000 strings that I want to categorize. The way I do this is to bucket it if it contains a set of words or phrases. The set of words is about 10,000. Ideally I would be able to support regular expressions, but I am focused on making it run fast right now. Example phrases:

ford, porsche, mazda...

I really dont want to match each word against the strings one by one, so I decided to use regular expressions. Unfortunately, I am running into a regular expression issue:

> > Regexp.new("(a)"*253)
> >     => /(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)...
> >
> > Regexp.new("(a)"*254)
> >     RegexpError: regular expression too big: /(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)(a)...

where a would be one of my words or phrases. Right now, I am planning on running 10,000 / 253 matches. I read that the length of the regex heavily impacts performance, but my regex match is really simple and the regexp is created very quickly. I would like to get around the limitation somehow, or use a better solution if anyone has any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, if you upgrade to Ruby 1.9, you can create huge regexes with no errors.

Comment: Hack: Create a list of regexes and run your strings against the list instead of just the one regex.

Comment: I thought ruby 1.9 might fix this problem. I'll go test it. I also thought about running a list of regexes, but this is too hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider other mechanisms for recognizing 10k words.

- Trie: Sometimes called a prefix tree, it is often used by spell checkers for doing word lookups.  See [Trie on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)
- DFA (deterministic finite automata): A DFA is often created by the lexer in a compiler for recognizing the tokens of the language.  A DFA runs very quickly.  Simple regexes are often compiled into DFAs.  See [DFA on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)